# How to group by month and year for entire calender year until this month in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, subquery

I have this query

```
DECLARE @DATE datetime 
SELECT @Date = '2014-04-01' 
SELECT @Date,  COUNT(*) FROM Claim C 
INNER JOIN Prop_Vehicles PV ON PV.Prop = C.Prop
WHERE PV.Vehicle IN (1,2) AND
C.DateCreate >= @DATE AND
ClaimCodeId =5
```

I want to group by month wise for the calnder year. For example

```
April 2014 - 200
May  2014 - 300
June 2014 - 500
.
.
october 2014 - 100
```

something like this. How to achieve it? Could someone help me how to split @Date into two fields and also group by month year wise until current month like I mentioned above?

I reckon datepart function would do? Let me also check that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case some months don't have data then this would skip those months.

If you want all months data even if value is zero, then you need to construct months table and join with it

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,C.DateCreate), 0), COUNT(*) FROM Claim C 
INNER JOIN Prop_Vehicles PV ON PV.Prop = C.Prop
and PV.Vehicle IN (1,2) AND
and C.DateCreate >= @DATE AND
AND ClaimCodeId =5 
group by DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,C.DateCreate), 0)
```

as per latest comment

here is the way to get all months data and also to display year and month

```
DECLARE @DATE datetime 
SELECT @Date = '2014-04-01'

;with cte
as
(
select DATEADD(month, datediff(month,0,@Date), 0) as monthVal,1 as N
union all
select DATEADD(month, datediff(month,0,@Date)+N, 0) as monthVal, N+1
FROM cte
WHERE n <=5
)
SELECT DATENAME(year, monthval) as Year, datename(month,monthVal) as Month, COUNT(*) FROM 
cte
left join Claim C
on DATEADD(month, datediff(month,0,C.DAteCreate)= cte.monthVal
INNER JOIN Prop_Vehicles PV ON PV.Prop = C.Prop
and PV.Vehicle IN (1,2) AND
and C.DateCreate >= @DATE AND
AND ClaimCodeId =5 
group by DATENAME(year, monthval) , datename(month,monthVal)
```

Comment: Its giving weird results when I remove ">" than from placing > in where condition DateCreate. I gave the date equal as "2014-04-01'. It doesn't give any record while if I have ">" in the query, it has a row for this date

Comment: Also, could you please explain how did you do it? or the DATEADD line please. Also, could you please help me return data for all months. Maybe, it would be easy/more readable for user if we mention month name and year rather than month name in numerics

Comment: thank you very much it helped me. But may I ask how to do for month and year wise in terms of strings like for example Jan 2014, Feb 2014 etc...And also how to use for months that doesn't have data

Comment: I am afraid it gives different result. For example, the first query you made gave me result upto October, however, the recent 2nd query you gave gives result only upto September. One month's data is not there. Any problem? Also, I do not see every month in your second query, I mean months having zero data are not displayed. Thus it is no difference from your first query in this aspect. Another error I found in your 2nd query, which says DATENAME needs 3 arguments, so I added a 0. Is it correct?

Comment: @Divine, you change value from 5 to 12 based on number of months needed, datename requires only 2 arguments , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx

Comment: Thank you, problem solved, thank you so much for your kind help, I appreciate it all :) :) Now my team lead advised me to create a SSRS report of this in VS2012, I am very new to create SSRS report, will do it. I will google out to do that now, if there are any pointers, please let me know. I will post you if I have queries :)

Comment: Radar, my TL verified my query(Which is yours) and optimized it by using a temp table for selecting month and year part and he did in such a way that it displays all months until now automatically. We do not have to specify "N" and of course he removed the CTE part